# Search for files with ' in them with the Google Drive Python API

Tags: python, google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-python-client

I'm using this code to find a file in My Drive with the Google Drive Python API:

```
results = service.files().list(q="name='"+finalfile+"'" fields="files(id)").execute()`
```

However, I get an error 400 whenever the file name has " ' " in it (I guess that it messes up the request). How can I search for a file with the apostrophe in it without crashing the program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your script is run, an error like `invalid syntax` occurs, because of no `,` between `q="name='"+finalfile+"'"` and `fields="files(id)"`. But in your question, you say `I get an error 400 whenever the file name has " ' " in it`. From this situation, I guessed that you might have miscopied your script.

About your error of `I get an error 400 whenever the file name has " ' " in it`, in your situation, please escape `'` like `name='sample\'sample'` and test it again. I thought that the reason for your current error might be due to this. In the case of your script, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```py
results = service.files().list(q="name='" + finalfile.replace("'", "\\'") + "'", fields="files(id)").execute()
```

- By this modification, when the value of `finalfile` is `sample'sample`, this file can be retrieved.

#### Reference:

- [Files: list](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list)

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a comma between your q parameter and your fields parameter

```
results = service.files().list(
        pageSize=10,
        q = "name='" + file_title + "'",
        fields="nextPageToken, files(id, name)").execute()
```